# ReactJS output console log duplicate

Tags: reactjs

When i write *console.log('constructor')* in class's constructor, the output duplicates the rendering.
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eigcg.jpg)
[rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQf0j.png)

Comment: Check your index file and remove StrickMode

Answer (score 9):

To solve the problem you have to disable the strict react mode  in index.js

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/96#discussion-3562310) will help you better understand why this is happening!

Answer (score 9):

You can disable doubled comments with [**React Developer Tools** browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi)

[image: React Developer Tools screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

If you're on development mode, try disabling "strict mode". On dev mode Reach renders components twice to make [dev-only checks](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) and tests to warn you of errors. https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/96#discussion-3562310

If you're not on dev mode:

This has nothing to do with the `console.log` duplicating the rendering. It's impossible that it may cause that, because console logging something doesn't affect a component's state, and it won't trigger a new render.

It's normal that components render more than once in a lot of cases

- Do you have any code updating state in your component? Like inside `componentDidMount` or anywhere else?
- Is a *parent* of this component updating state anywhere? If so, it will cause itself to re-render, which includes its children re-rendering too.

In short, this is not being caused by your console log. If you remove it you won't "see" the double render because it happens fast and you don't have a point of reference (like a log in your console), but it still happens.

Comment: This is a new App of create-react-app and i inserted into the constructor *console.log('constructor')*. But i don't know why the output is duplicated

Comment: I recommend you read [this](https://mariosfakiolas.com/blog/my-react-components-render-twice-and-drive-me-crazy/) it goes over some causes and explanations.

If I answered your question, please mark it as accepted 